# Why does the Click effect of a Button get removed when I change the Background Color of the Button in .NET Maui?

Tags: xaml, maui

I just created a blank new Maui Project and placed a button and changed the Background Color and now the Click effect that you normally get is getting removed when the button has the White Color, how can I bring this effect back?

Comment: I will need the XAML of your page, and the code behind.

Comment: 1. May I know on what platform you are targeting? 2.Please help create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add it to your post.